# Laravel page loading issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, clockwork, barryvdh, laravel-telescope

I got a loading problem with all my pages in my Laravel app, they all need over 2400 ms to load, the thing is they worked fine and I really don't know where I messed up

I ran a login page for the this app and one another with same login (same pc with different ports) and these are the results in telescope:

Slow app
[image: Slow app]

OK app
[image: OK app]

also tried clockwork and got this result for the slow app: [clockwork result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0zSO.jpg), it says 2580 ms on the App and 2492 ms on Controller

Also tried laravel/debugbar on a view :

```
Route::get("/welcome", function () {
    return view('/welcome');
});
```

> welcome.blade.php: welcome

and im getting 2.64sec on creating

```
Illuminate\Routing\Events\Routing (78.68ms)
Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched (2.31ms)
creating: .welcome (2.64s)
Illuminate\Routing\Events\PreparingResponse (115μs)
composing: .welcome (1.15ms)
Illuminate\Routing\Events\ResponsePrepared (17.62ms)
Illuminate\Routing\Events\PreparingResponse (1.16ms)
Illuminate\Routing\Events\ResponsePrepared (53μs)
```

**Solution to my problem**

didn't get anything from debugg(im a noob) so i started reading about "Laravel Lifecycle" and saw that composer loads first. Started unninstalling some packages and it worked! Dunno why but this icon package was my high load problem: **"postare/blade-mdi"**

Comment: If you solved your problem post solution as answer (it's fine to anawer own equation)